# Javascript and 3 parameter filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to understand the 3-parameter `filter` function in Javascript.
What is this piece of code doing? (I am currently refactoring existing code in system.)

```
docs = _.cloneDeep(docs.filter((v, i, a) => a.findIndex(t => (t.documentNumber === v.documentNumber)) === i));
```

Comment: v = current element, i = index of current element, a = is the original array. this code seems checking to itself.

Comment: Since you are using `lodash` anyway, you might consider rewriting this as `_.cloneDeep(_.uniqBy(doc => doc.documentNumber))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callback for [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is given three arguments, the current element, the index, and the original array.

The code you provided creates an array with unique `documentNumber` properties, as for each element, it looks for the index of the first element that has the same documentNumber as it; if the index of the found element is the same as the current index, then this element is the first occurrence of that property in the array and only then will the callback return true which retains the element. It will remove duplicates.

See also: [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: That's a good explanation of some rather obscure code

Comment: That's all there is to it. It may look intimidating at first, but after breaking it down, it becomes a lot easier to understand.

Comment: This is one of the easiest ways to remove the duplicates. One can also use a `Set`.

Answer (score 2):

It filters to the first instance of unique a documentNumber

```js
const docs = [
  { documentNumber: 1 },
  { documentNumber: 1 },
  { documentNumber: 2 },
  { documentNumber: 3 },
  { documentNumber: 4 },
  { documentNumber: 4 },
  { documentNumber: 4 },
  { documentNumber: 5 },
  { documentNumber: 6 },
  { documentNumber: 7 },
  { documentNumber: 7 },
  { documentNumber: 1 },
  { documentNumber: 8 }
];

let results = docs.filter((v, i, a) => a.findIndex(t => (t.documentNumber === v.documentNumber)) === i);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: how have you written it by the way to remove duplicates?

Comment: It is the function you have in your question, I am just demonstrating what it does.

Comment: Because findIndex returns the first instance where where the documentNumber is equal to the current item being filtered only the first instance of any documentNumber will be in the final results.